# asp.net c# app routing

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes, global-asax

I've been trying to get some routing up and running. I basically want this url:

www.example.com/SomebodysName

or

www.example.com/agents/somebodysname

..to go to...

www.example.com/portfolio.aspx?ran=somebodysname

I have tried to use an example from MSDN, using globax.asax like this:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        RegisterRoutes(System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes);

    }

public static void RegisterRoutes(System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapPageRoute("", "agents/{name}", "portfolio.aspx?ran={name}");
    }
```

but I can't get it to work, it says Routing does not exist in the namespace System.Web.
how can I get it to work this way or perhaps another way (web.config?)

Comment: Suggest editing your question to show the error and how your code is setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure your Global.asax has a using statement for:

```
using System.Web.Routing;
```

You can map your route like this without the param on the target physical aspx page:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("AgentPortfolioByName", "agents/{name}", "portfolio.aspx");
```

In the code-behind in portfolio.aspx.cs, you can simply refer to the `name` value like this:

```
 string name = Page.RouteData.Values["name"].ToString();
```

This will ensure your ASP.NET 4+ site will have the URL routing working as you expect/describe.

Comment: My Global.asax looks like this now:
`<%@ Application Language="C#" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Routing" %>

<script runat="server">
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        RegisterRoutes(System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes); 
    }

    public static void RegisterRoutes(System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapPageRoute("AgentPortfolioByName", "agents/{name}", "portfolio.aspx"); 
    } `

But I am still getting the same assembly error
Error 18 The type or namespace name 'Routing' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (ar..

Comment: @Jesper is it ASP.NET **3.5** or **4.0** `webforms` website that you have setup?

Comment: @balalexandre. I am not sure :) In references, it says version 3.5.0.0, but in Build -> Target Framework, it says 4.0. Also, this is a website (folder structure) not a web-application project, thus global.asax does not have a code-behind file, if that matters...

Comment: I have gotten this to work, now that I have fixed the configuration to target .net 4.0. It works like a charm, so thanks a lot. One interesting thing though is that when loading:
**www.website.com/agents/agent%20name** all the images/js/css are missing. I guess it's because I now have to add  `../` due to the "agents" folder even though it doesn't exist. Is that usual?