# Routing removes images/js/css etc

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes, path

I have gotten [this Routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376729/asp-net-c-sharp-app-routing/7376749#7376749) to work.  It is Dot Net 4.0 System.Web.Routing.

But the problem is that all paths in the document are no longer working.  If I want the page to work both as

```
www.website.com/agents/Agent Name
```

And the "real" address

```
www.website.com/portfolio.aspx?aid=123
```

What do I do?  Of course I can make it work by using absolute URLs like

```
<img src="http://www.website.com/images/image.png" alt="" />
```

But is that the way to go?

---

I actually found the answer myself:

> routes.Add("AgentFolderGraphicsRoute", new
>   Route("agents/graphics/{folder}/{filename}.{ext}", new
>   ImageRouteHandler()));

---

```
public class ImageRouteHandler : IRouteHandler
    {
        public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
        {
            string folder = requestContext.RouteData.Values["folder"] as string;
            string filename = requestContext.RouteData.Values["filename"] as string;
            string ext = requestContext.RouteData.Values["ext"] as string;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filename))
            {
                requestContext.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
                requestContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 404;
                requestContext.HttpContext.Response.End();
            }
            else
            {
                requestContext.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
                requestContext.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = GetContentType(requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.ToString());

                // find physical path to image here.  
                string filepath;
                if (folder != null) filepath = requestContext.HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/graphics/" + folder + "/" + filename + "." + ext);
                else filepath = requestContext.HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/graphics/" + filename + "." + ext);

                requestContext.HttpContext.Response.WriteFile(filepath);
                requestContext.HttpContext.Response.End();
            }
            return null;
        }

        private static string GetContentType(String path)
        {
            switch (System.IO.Path.GetExtension(path))
            {
                case ".bmp": return "Image/bmp";
                case ".gif": return "Image/gif";
                case ".jpg": return "Image/jpeg";
                case ".png": return "Image/png";
                default: break;
            }
            return "";
        }
```

Which is a slightly modified version of the one on this page:

http://www.phpvs.net/2009/08/06/aspnet-mvc-how-to-route-to-images-or-other-file-types/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the first thing in your `RegisterRoutes()` method is:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute( "{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}" );
```

This will instruct the routing engine to ignore requests for resources (like images or files).

Comment: I don't think, I can do that in a non-MVC app.

Comment: MVC is really just an ASP.NET extension. The routing engine in MVC is the same used in WebForms, so it should work. Did you try it?

Comment: I can't, because System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection does not contain IgnoreRoute

Comment: You must be using the .NET 3.5 .dll. The `RouteCollection` class in 4.0 does implement the `IgnoreRoute()` method. Glad you found something that worked, though. :)